# How to retrieve a subset of fields using the Java MongoDB driver?

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, mongodb-java

new poster here, I found this previous post but it's on C#,
I tried doing this query straight into the java code of a JSP page, for some reason, it doesn't accept the info in the {} of the find() query and just gives out an error...

So peeps, how do I do this in Java:

```
// retrieve ssn field for documents where last_name == 'Smith':
db.users.find({last_name: 'Smith'}, {'ssn': 1});
```

Thanks!

PS: why the hell does C# have the nice little .Exclude() and .Include() commands and java doesn't? *cries*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java driver follows the exact same API as the shell. Just pass a `DBObject` containing your field projection as the second argument to `find` or `findOne`

As far as I know the official C# driver doesn't expose Include() and Exclude() methods as they violate the standard API.

Comment: well that's the problem, I try to create a DBObject, but if I for instance want to the following query:
coll.find({},{"_id":0});
however, it does seem to read and connect when I use a DBObject, but when I test it, I only get an empty JSON string back, like:
[{}]

Comment: here's the code for this part of the problem:

`Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost");
  DB db = m.getDB("names");
  DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("names");
 
  String jsonData = "[";
  int count = 0;
  for(DBObject items : coll.find())
  {
   BasicDBObject ugh = new BasicDBObject();
   ugh.putAll(items);
   if(count == 0){jsonData+=ugh.get("names").toString();}
   else {jsonData += "," + ugh.get("names").toString();;}
   count++;
  }
  jsonData += "]";`

Comment: well it does work, am now able to get it all into a string, the idea is to add this data to a dojo.grid.DataGrid object, but for some reason it's not accepting the string as input data, however this part of the problem is working!
thanks for your help!